# Session not retaining in Ajax calls for SQLServer mode

Tags: ajax, session

I Try to create a session during the Ajax call when the user logs in.  All works fine when i am in Inproc Mode . 
When i changed it to SQLServere mode, Everythough the sessions are created when i see in debug mode,  NONE of the sessions created during Ajax are retained after that doing a  post back. 
         Where as other sessions that are created during a button click or page load  (non Ajax) stays..  Any idea on why it is not retaining?

It is a pretty startight forward ..  The ajax call is

```
function Authenticate(userID) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/GlobalService.asmx/CreateAuthentication",
                data: JSON.stringify({ ID: userID }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                   //Some simple logic to show username
                }
            });
```

The Code behind for the ajax call

```
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
 public void CreateAuthentication(string UserID)
        {
            if (UserID != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = UserID;
                    }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Not Working Config :

```
  <sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI" cookieless="false" timeout="3" />
```

Comment: Did you find the reason behind this? I seem to have the same problem right now

Comment: Never mind. In my case it was because a non serializable class had made it's way into the session and the error handling wasn't set up correctly. In Inproc mode it works because it doesn't need serializable

Answer (score 0):

This is from ages ago but as I'm here

(1) If your session was setup incorrectly any errors would be masked by the catch all block.

(2) To trace the error I would (in IE11) press F12, trace network calls. Chances are you'll see an error message in the response section about why it can't write the session to the database

Also you are using SQLExpress so I don't think session expiry works by default but that's an aside